# Problemas con las etiquetas html a en github pages

Tags: html5, github, github-pages

tengo una etiqueta a en mi html

```
<a href="www.facebook.com"> Facebook</a>
```

y mi pagina la aloje en github pages pero cuando estoy viendo la pagina desde github pages y doy click en mi link facebook sale un error 404 ya que en lugar de redireccionar a [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) redirecciona a [www.user.github.io/repo/www.facebook.com](http://www.user.github.io/repo/www.facebook.com)

Alguien sabe como solucionar eso?

Comment: te falta el protocolo `https://` sino lo toma como archivo o carpeta relativo al documento

Comment: Como dice el compañero @aloMalbarez intenta añadir el protocolo de seguridad, por que sino se piensa que estas llamando a una ruta de tu propia pagina.

Comment: @aloMalbarez póngalo en una respuesta, luego esto queda ahí tirado y el bot hará de las suyas reviviéndolo en 3 años :-S

Answer (score 2):

Añade el protocolo, también llamado [`esquema`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localizador_de_recursos_uniforme#Esquema_URL). Preferentemente `https` en lugar de `http`, sino interpreta estas llamando a una ruta, carpeta o archivo relativo a tu propio proyecto.

por ejemplo:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```